# How can I "select" a new UITableView row after adding a new managed object, within a UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I've had the UITableView/UISplitViewController and detail working for a while now, so when you manually tap a row, the detail item shows etc.

When I'm only viewing the master/UITableView and I add a new managed object... the new row appears, but I always have to manually select this.

When the user taps the + button, I have a pop up dialog box to enter the details, then they tap Save and the dialog dismisses, and the new row is there.  I can select the new row programmatically, and have tried to trigger some of the events like didSelect but nothing seems to work.  I just want the detail view controller to move into place after the dialog disappears.

Comment: So after the dialog disappears you'd like to show the detail view controller. So why not call `showDetailViewController`?

Comment: Tried that among other things... I think my issue was that it's a detail view controller within a SplitViewController.  I had to grab the split view controller, then the detail controller from that, and then configure it.  Will edit code to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

```
let indexPath = // Calculate indexPath for your new added rows
// On the cell selection programetically
tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
```

Comment: Tried that first, all it does is highlight the row.  My code for showing the detail controller is triggered by a segue defined in the Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Update:  I wasn't considering the navigation controller / split view controller when trying to display the view.  Here's what I ended up with:

```
 dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

    if let controller = self.master?.splitViewController {
       let controllers = controller.viewControllers
       if let controller = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController {
           self.master?.detailViewController = controller
           controller.managedObjectContext = self.master!.managedObjectContext
           controller.detailItem = self.composition
             self.masterTableView?.splitViewController!.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewController.DisplayMode.primaryHidden
        }
     }
 })
```